# How to duplicate product template in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am very new to opencart but I think this is easy and best solution out there. Although playing with templates is not a joy...

I am struggling to create some additional template pages. For example I have two types of products and category pages. I want to different templates for different products. In opencart you have only one layout for products.

What I thought to do is to make a duplicate of product layout. I got some help online but I am still not sure what more is needed. This is what I've done so far...

1 - Copy the controller file of catalog/controller/product/product.php and changed to catalog/controller/product/product-2.php. Then I changed this in controller:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product-2.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product-2.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/product/product-2.tpl';
        }
```

2 - Then I copied the product language file and save as product-2

3 - After that I copied the actual tpl file and save as product-2

It was looking fine but if I try to make some changes to product-2.tpl nothing changes. Do I have to copy some more files to complete it?

Comment: Use this - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here ;

http://pranshuarya.com/jaal/Development/opencart-creating-a-new-viewtemplate.html

This was the second option of the real solution for "completely new layout" request.
Both can be used. Your solution is time saver if you will not need  a new controller routine.But that way is more flexible.

Here are the steps ;

- Add a new controller file to /catalog/controller.  call something like new_layout.php... copy if there is a similar controller already. Be sure to change controller name as i told in my comment below.
- Add a new view file in your theme folder ... like controller if you wish you can copy a simiplar view files content and modify as you wish.
- Add the new layout either from admin panel System/Design/Layouts or from MYSQL table directly as explained in the link above.
- It's ok now. Just add some modules in this layout view and enjoy.

Comment: I processed the workaround now ... one little thing to add.... You must also change the controller name to - for instance from ControllerProductProduct to ControllerProductCampaigns if your new layout name is Campaigns-

Answer (score 1):

After search and doing lot of research and mind-boggling, i found a very useful  method to do what i want to do. in this way i have fully control of the opencart theme system. i can make as many different layouts as i wanted. i dont have to use VQmod neither have to make any controller but you have to use the existing controllers like product, category etc. if you are making your own controller even then it works.

here are the steps to follow to achieve different template  for different categories, products and common pages.

i am here doing the example of products. 
1- create custom template of product in product folder of the theme. e.g customproduct.tpl
2- now customize it as you wanted.create a product and take the id of it. id is very important here.
3- go to the controller catalog/controller/product/product.php
4- find this code

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
  $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
            } else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/product/product.tpl';
            }
```

5- now you have to use the simple if else condition. for example

```
//42 is the id of the product 
 if($this->request->get['product_id'] == 42){
            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
            }
        }
        else{
            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
            }
        }
```

that's it job Done ;)
you can do the same thing for other controllers.